# Java 8 Copy Map with Filter of Another Map

Tags: java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I am trying to filter an original map by comparing with a condition map which has only the key sets with id. Based on the condition map, I want to filter from the original map.

The original map which I have is,

```
Map<Integer, AppFeatureDTO> appFeatureMap = new TreeMap<>();
```

which will result like,

```
{
    "101": {
        "id": 101,
        "subFeature": {
            "1": {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "Title Value",
                "desc": "Description Value"
            }
        }
    },
    "102": {
        "id": 102,
        "subFeature": {
            "1": {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "Title Value",
                "desc": "Description Value"
            }
        }
    },
    "103": {
        "id": 103,
        "subFeature": {
            "1": {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "Title Value",
                "desc": "Description Value"
            },
            "2": {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "Title Value",
                "desc": "Description Value"
            },
            "3": {
                "id": 3,
                "title": "Title Value",
                "desc": "Description Value"
            },
            "4": {
                "id": 4,
                "title": "Title Value",
                "desc": "Description Value"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the corresponding classes are:

```
class AppFeatureDTO {
    private int id;
    private Map<Integer, AppSubFeatureDTO> subFeature;
}
class AppSubFeatureDTO{
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
}
```

then I have a filter map,

```
Map<Integer, FeatureDTO> conditionFilterMap = new TreeMap<>();
```

which is resulting like,

```
{
    "101": {
        "id": 101,
        "subFeature": {
            "1": {
                "id": 1,
            }
        }
    },
    "103": {
        "id": 103,
        "subFeature": {
            "2": {
                "id": 2
            },
            "4": {
                "id": 4
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the corresponding classes for the filter map are,

```
class FeatureDTO {
    private int id;
    private Map<Integer, SubFeatureDTO> subFeature;
}
class SubFeatureDTO{
    private int id;
}
```

I want to filter the result map using conditionFilterMap like,

```
{
"101": {
    "id": 101,
    "subFeature": {
        "1": {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Title Value",
            "desc": "Description Value"
        }
    }
},
"103": {
    "id": 103,
    "subFeature": {
        "2": {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Title Value",
            "desc": "Description Value"
        },
        "4": {
            "id": 4,
            "title": "Title Value",
            "desc": "Description Value"
        }
    }
}
```

}

I'm using spring modelMapper to copy `AppFeatureDTO` to `FeatureDTO`. But, filtering the map, I didn't get clue.

Could you please suggest how to get the `resultMap` using Java 8?

Even I couldn't imagine a simple solution using Java 7 or 6 also.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the map key is the same as the id field:

```
Map<Integer, AppFeatureDTO> resultMap = conditionFilterMap.values().stream()
        .map(FeatureDTO::getId)
        .map(appFeatureMap::get)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(AppFeatureDTO::getId, a -> new AppFeatureDTO(a.getId(),
                conditionFilterMap.get(a.getId()).getSubFeature().values().stream()
                        .map(SubFeatureDTO::getId)
                        .map(a.getSubFeature()::get)
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(AppSubFeatureDTO::getId, x -> x)))));
```

If you need `TreeMap`, add the arguments `(a, b) -> a, TreeMap::new` to the `Collectors.toMap` calls.

The non-stream version doesn't really look any worse:

```
Map<Integer, AppFeatureDTO> resultMap = new TreeMap<>();
for (FeatureDTO f : conditionFilterMap.values()) {
    AppFeatureDTO a = appFeatureMap.get(f.getId());
    Map<Integer, AppSubFeatureDTO> resultSub = new TreeMap<>();
    for (SubFeatureDTO s : f.getSubFeature().values()) {
        resultSub.put(s.getId(), a.getSubFeature().get(s.getId()));
    }
    resultMap.put(a.getId(), new AppFeatureDTO(a.getId(), resultSub));
}
```

Comment: This has error also, can you review it once. ass per the first snippet 4th line, you are passing like key,value to a constructor. Is it typo? or I need to create constructor?

Comment: @Shakthi you can rewrite the code to work without such a constructor, but it would become much more complicated, so creating such a constructor is recommended.

Comment: @Shakthi If you don't have a constructor, are you creating instances with `new AppFeatureDTO()` and calling `setWhatever` to set the field values? If so, I would strongly recommend adding basic constructors to your classes that take the field values as parameters, most IDEs can generate them for you.